# How many $2$'s are needed?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, contest-math

There is a positive integer $N$. $N$ is made up of only two distinct digits- $2$ and $3$. $N+18$ is divisible by $37$. What is the minunum amount of times the number $2$ can appear in $N$? I'm pretty sure the answer is only one time. But how can I prove this?

Comment: are there any better tags I could use?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't share your optimism; the smallest count of twos I managed to come up was three.

Comment: @PeterKošinár but is it possible to prove that the smallest amount of two's is 3?

Comment: Note that $1000\equiv 1 \mod 37$ so you can reduce the problem to analysing the sum of digits (with some cases to check).

Comment: @MarkBennet Thanks. That should be an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with a simple observation:

The number $37$ plays very nicely with powers of $10$... The value $10^m$ can only have three possible remainders modulo $37$: $1$, $10$ and $26$. If $N+18$ is divisible by $37$, $N$ must be congruent to $19$ modulo $37$. This observation will be quite useful in subsequent thoughts.

The number $N=2323323$ satisfies the given conditions and contains three twos. In order to show that we cannot satisfy the conditions given with fewer twos, we need to consider three cases:

- Numbers consisting solely of digit $3$: An $m$-digit number of this form is equal to $$\frac{3}{9}(10^m-1)=\frac{1}{3}(10^m-1)$$
  Using the observation mentioned above, we find that such numbers produce remainders $0$, $3$ and $33$ modulo $37$; none of which is equal to the desired $19$.
- Numbers having exactly one occurrence of $2$: They can be obtained by the numbers in the preceding group by subtracting number of the form $10^k$ with $k\leq m$. The observation allows us to quickly conclude that the only remainders of such numbers modulo $37$ are $2$,
  $7$, $11$, $14$, $23$, $27$, $30$, $32$ and $36$.
- Numbers having exactly two occurrences of $2$ are just as easy to deal with; there are just more remainders to cover... but still no $19$ among them.

Comment: How did you come up with $N=2323323$ or any N with three digits 2 to begin with?

Comment: Being lazy, I just ran a simple computer search :-) It can be done by hand quite easily too, though: Make a table consisting of four rows and $37$ columns (each column corresponding to one remainder modulo $37$). Mark cells $0$, $3$ and $33$ in the first row (those can be produced with no twos). Connect each marked cell in the first row with three cells in the second row; those $1$, $10$ and $26$ positions to the left of it (wrapping around from left to right if necessary). Do the same for third and fourth row. The path from cell $19$ in the last row tells you how to build your number.

Answer (score 2):

Just another observation since I'm late to the party.

We can also use an [algorithm for divisibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule#Notable_examples), which is to group the digits by threes from the right, and add them, repeating the process until we have a three digit number.  If that's divisible by 37 then so is the original number.

If the number is of the form $33...333$, then the number $+18$ is $33...351$.  The grouping sums form a pattern:

$$351, 354, 384, 684, 687, 717, 18, 21, 51, 351, ...$$

As none of these are divisible by $37$, there must be at least one $2$.

From there, it would remain to show that introducing one $2$, and then two $2$s, wouldn't produce any numbers divisible by $37$ either, and then it becomes a matter of searching.

You might be able to see that each $2$ rolls back the digit in the same place it lies in the group of three.  Then, $687-21=666$, which is two $2$'s in the tens place, and one $2$ in the ones place.

Hence, not only does $3323322$ work, but also $2323323$ and $3322323$!

Answer (score 1):

Let $k$ be the minimal possible number of $2$'s. Let $N$ be a minimal number of the given form with $k$ $2$'s.
Since $333\cdot 10^n \equiv 0\pmod{ 37}$, $N$ does not contain three consecutive $3$'s. Thus only finitely many candidates need to be checked with less than three $2$'s. In fact, if $N$ has only $3$'s, then  $N\equiv 0, 3,$ or $33\pmod{37}$. If there is one digit $2$ somewhere, then $1,10,$ or $26$ is subtracted depending on its position; and the same for a possible second $2$ occuring. We need to achieve $19\pmod{37}$. Obviously, zero $2$'s don't work.
If we add $1,10,26$ to $19$, we get
$$20,29,8 $$
which is a set  disjoint from $\{0,3,33\}$.
All sums of two nombers in $\{1,10,26\}$ plus $19$ are
$$21, 30, 9, 2,18, 34.$$
again no match with $0,3,33$.
We conclude $k>2$. From $3323322$ we learn that $k=3$.